# clang-format - Format long macro

Tags: c++, c, clang-format

I'm here because honestly, I can't figure out this one.
My problem lies in how `clang-format` rearranges long preprocessor definition.

Here's what my code look like, after formating.

```
#define CMD_FRAME_PACKET_HEADER_SIZE                                                                                   \
    (CMD_FRAME_SOF_SIZE + CMD_FRAME_MSG_ID_SIZE + CMD_FRAME_CMD_CODE_SIZE + CMD_FRAME_CMD_STATE_SIZE +                 \
     CMD_FRAME_DATA_LENGTH_SIZE)
#define CMD_FRAME_PACKET_FOOTER_SIZE      (CMD_FRAME_CRC_SIZE + CMD_FRAME_EOF_SIZE)
#define CMD_FRAME_PACKET_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE (2 * CMD_FRAME_DATA_FIELDS_MAX_SIZE)
#define CMD_FRAME_PACKET_PAYLOAD_MIN_SIZE (0)
#define CMD_FRAME_PACKET_MAX_SIZE                                                                                      \
    (CMD_FRAME_PACKET_HEADER_SIZE + CMD_FRAME_PACKET_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE + CMD_FRAME_PACKET_FOOTER_SIZE)
#define CMD_FRAME_PACKET_MIN_SIZE                                                                                      \
    (CMD_FRAME_PACKET_HEADER_SIZE + CMD_FRAME_PACKET_PAYLOAD_MIN_SIZE + CMD_FRAME_PACKET_FOOTER_SIZE)
```

Here's what I like to see:

```
#define CMD_FRAME_PACKET_HEADER_SIZE      (CMD_FRAME_SOF_SIZE + CMD_FRAME_MSG_ID_SIZE + CMD_FRAME_CMD_CODE_SIZE \
                                          + CMD_FRAME_CMD_STATE_SIZE + CMD_FRAME_DATA_LENGTH_SIZE)
#define CMD_FRAME_PACKET_FOOTER_SIZE      (CMD_FRAME_CRC_SIZE + CMD_FRAME_EOF_SIZE)
#define CMD_FRAME_PACKET_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE (2 * CMD_FRAME_DATA_FIELDS_MAX_SIZE)
#define CMD_FRAME_PACKET_PAYLOAD_MIN_SIZE (0)
#define CMD_FRAME_PACKET_MAX_SIZE         (CMD_FRAME_PACKET_HEADER_SIZE + CMD_FRAME_PACKET_PAYLOAD_MAX_SIZE \
                                          + CMD_FRAME_PACKET_FOOTER_SIZE)
#define CMD_FRAME_PACKET_MIN_SIZE         (CMD_FRAME_PACKET_HEADER_SIZE + CMD_FRAME_PACKET_PAYLOAD_MIN_SIZE \
                                          + CMD_FRAME_PACKET_FOOTER_SIZE)
```

For those interested, here is my `.clang-format`

```
---
#
# Global style
BasedOnStyle: Microsoft
#
# Basic
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
ColumnLimit: 120
UseTab: Never
#
# Function and macro
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
BinPackParameters: true
AlignConsecutiveMacros: Consecutive
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
#
# if and switch case
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: true
AlignTrailingComments: true
IndentCaseLabels: true
BraceWrapping:
  AfterCaseLabel: true
#
# Other
SpaceInEmptyBlock: true
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: Consecutive
SpacesInContainerLiterals: true
# AlignArrayOfStructures: Right
```

Comment: FWIW, I like what Clang formatter did :)

Comment: Like for all formatting, it's a matter of personal taste :)

Answer (score 0):

"what I like to see" involves the layout of one macro to depend on others.  Should that "other" macros only depend on nearby macros, *all* macros in the .c file, *all* macros in the .c and .h files or what?

Consider how one long macro would impact the others

```
#define CMD_FRAME_PACKET_FOOTER_SIZE_AALKJSLFAKJFALFEUEUFELUFEU (0)
#define CMD_FRAME_PACKET_HEADER_SIZE                            (CMD_FRAME_SOF_SIZE \
                                                                 + CMD_FRAME_MSG_ID_SIZE \
                                                                 + CMD_FRAME_CMD_CODE_SIZE \
                                                                 + CMD_FRAME_CMD_STATE_SIZE \
                                                                 + CMD_FRAME_DATA_LENGTH_SIZE)
```

The desired format is higher maintenance and not effective use of valuable coder time.  OTOH, your own time is yours to do as you will.  Yet since much programming is paid by others, payers would not likely want to pay for this and so *Clang* (or other simple auto formatting) becomes more common and familiar/understandable.

I recommend to format code based on your group's coding standard.

Comment: "desired format is higher maintenance". This is exactly why I'm using clang.  "I recommend to format code based on your group's coding standard." excellent suggestion. That said, I'm the guy who set the group standard.

Comment: @gberth It appears your group's coding standard is not supported by Clang.  Perhaps your group could convince Clang authors to support it (I suspect difficult) or your group could shift their standard (easier given that it is size one).  (Or write your own formatter.)

Comment: That seems to be the best course of action. Thanks.